# CRUD Resource incl Sub-Resource in MANY_MANY relation with RESTfull JSON-API

Tags: php, crud, yii

I use the YII Framework for a Web-Application with a RESTfull JSON-API and the CRUD operations. For the API i use the [restfullyii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/restfullyii/) extension. Is there an alternative?

There are three tables (User, Event and event_participant) with a MANY_MANY relation. This is the relation in the **Event** Model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'participants' => array(
            self::MANY_MANY,
            'User',
            'event_participant(studiobooking, user)'
        )
    );
}
```

I want to use the CRUD Operations to CRUD the Event with the User Sub-Resource in one Request. It works to GET the Resource with the Sub-Resource. Now i want to save/update/delete the Resource incl. Sub-Resource, for example a POST request with this data:

```
{
    "event": "eventname",
    "start": "2013-02-17 14:30:00",
    "end": "2013-02-17 16:00:00",
    "participants": [ {
        "id": "2"
    },{
        "id": "3"
    }]
}
```

This should create the new event in the Event table and the new id from the event with the participant ids in the "event_participant" table. Is this possible with the YII framework?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to come up with your own code to do this, but it is relatively straight forward. Here's an example. Note: This was "coded" in the StackOverflow editor, so it is not production ready, tested code :)

```
//in your Event model
public function associateWithParticipant(int $participantId)
{
    //you may check if the participant even exists before inserting it, but this is a detail
    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_event_participant_pivot (event_id, participant_id) VALUES(:event_id,:participant_id)";
    $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $command->bindParam(":event_id",$this->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $command->bindParam(":participant_id",$participantId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $command->execute();
}

//in your Event controller (or ApiController or whatsoever you are using)
public function actionCreateEvent()
{
    //if for any reason POST is not giving you any JSON try file_get_contents('php://input')
    if(isset($_POST['Event'])) {
        $data = CJSON::decode($_POST['Event']);
        //first, make sure this is transactional or an error while adding participants could leave
        //your db in an inconsistent state
        $tx = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
        try {
            //create the event
            $event = new Event();
            $event->attributes = $data;

            //save it and if that works check if there is anything in the participants "array"
            if($event->save()) {
                if(isset($data['participants'])) {
                    //check if this is a correct JSON array
                    if(is_array($data['participants']) {
                        foreach($data['participants'] as $participantEntry) {
                            //add a new row to the pivot table
                            $event->associateWithParticipant($participantEntry['id']);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new CHttpException(400,'Participants has to be a JSON array');
                    }
                }
            }
            //commit the transaction as we are finished now
            $tx->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //roll back the tx if an error occurred
            throw new CException("I've seen the horrors of bad coding")
            $tx->rollback();
        }
    }
}
```